# Getting wrong value in variable in C using structs

Tags: c, data-structures, struct

I have problems getting the right value for cociente; every time I run it, cociente is printed as 1 but that is not the value I want to assign it, this is the code where I print:

`printf("\nEl valor del cociente es: %d",(polinomio_->polinomio->cociente));`.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct termino
{
  int exponente;
  float cociente;
} termino;

typedef struct polinomio
{
  termino* polinomio;
  int size;
} polinomio;

void multiplicarEscalar(int escalar, termino* term){
    term->cociente = (term->cociente)*(float)escalar;
}
main()
{
  int size_;
  termino* terminos;
  int cociente_temporal;
  polinomio *polinomio_;
  //polinomio_ = malloc(sizeof(polinomio));
  //printf("%d",(sizeof(polinomio_)*2));

  printf("Bienvenido al cálculo de operaciones usando 1 polinomio.\n");
  printf("Ingrese la cantidad de términos que tendrá el polinomio.");  
  scanf("%d",&size_);
  terminos =(termino*) malloc(sizeof(termino) * size_);
  polinomio_ = (polinomio*) malloc(sizeof(polinomio) );
  polinomio_->polinomio = terminos;
  polinomio_->size = size_;

  printf("Ingrese el cociente 0:\n");
  scanf("%d",&cociente_temporal);
  polinomio_->polinomio->cociente = cociente_temporal;
  //multiplicarEscalar(2,polinomio_->polinomio);
  printf("\nEl valor del cociente es: %d",(polinomio_->polinomio->cociente));
  free(polinomio_);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `"%d"` to print a float. That leads to undefined behavior.

Instead of

```
printf("\nEl valor del cociente es: %d",(polinomio_->polinomio->cociente));
```

use

```
printf("\nEl valor del cociente es: %f",(polinomio_->polinomio->cociente));
//                                 ^^^
```